# My Code is not running properly

Tags: c

This is my code in C. I don't understand what is wrong in it. As you can see there are 6 printf statements. I want my program to find the area and circumference of a circle first and then the area and perimeter of a square, so it will ask the user to input the diameter of the circle and then it will print the area and circumference, next it will ask the user to input the length of the square and then print the area and perimeter of the square. The problem is when I run my code, it asks to input the diameter and then prints the area and circumference and then ends there. It doesn't ask to input the length of the square.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main (void) {
    //Circle
    const float  Pi = 3.142;
    float radius = 0.0;
    float dia = 0.0;
    float area = 0.0;
    float circum = 0.0;
    printf("Input the diameter of the circle:" );
    scanf("%f", &dia);
    radius = dia/2;
    area = radius*radius*Pi;
    circum = 2*Pi*radius;
    printf("\nThe area of the circle is %.2f",area);
    printf("\nThe circumference of the circle is %.2f",circum);
    //Square
    float len = 0.0;
    float areaS = 0.0;
    float periS = 0.0;
    printf("\nInput the length of the square:");
    scanf("%f",&len);
    areaS = len*len;
    periS = 4*len;
    printf("The area of the square is %.2f", areaS);
    printf("The perimeter of the square is %.2f", periS);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Do you get build errors? Do you get runtime errors (crashes)? Do you get unexpected output?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is the **return 0;**

You leave the program and you can not see the results because there aren't more scanf to pause.

You need to put a getchar or a system pause before the return 0 and you will see the results.

Comment: `the problem is the return 0`  How ? Why to delete `return 0` ?

Comment: Well, you if you put a system("pause") before the return (0), is better.

Comment: Why would this be a problem? If started from within e.g. Visual Studio then it generally asks for a key after console programs have finished, so you can see the output. And if run from the console (on any platform) the output will also be there. The only place this is a problem is if running by e.g. double-clicking on the programs icon. And we *don't know* if this is the actual problem the OP have.

Comment: Yes `system("pause") before the return (0)` that is fine . But how is `return 0` creating problem ?

Comment: Not, is not a problem. Return (0) is perfect, is a good way to use in your code. return (0) = ok return (1) = when you want to leve for a determinate reason, or other values.

Comment: @Braisly: If it's not a problem then why does the first sentence of your answer still say it is?